# How to convert the values of CheckBoxes into a sum of integers?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I created 3 `CheckBox` containing the colors: red, blue and white. Each checkbox contains a value. The red checkbox contains the value 10. The blue checkbox contains the value 20. And the white checkbox contains the value 30.
I would like that when any user clicked on any `CheckBox` and then pressed the `calculateResult` button, the `textView` called `showResult` would show the sum of the `CheckBox` values ​​clicked by the user.

My code:

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox red;
    CheckBox blue;
    CheckBox white;
    Button calculateResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        red = findViewById(R.id.red);
        blue = findViewById(R.id.blue);
        white = findViewById(R.id.white);
        calculateResult = findViewById(R.id.calculateResult);

     final TextView showResult = findViewById(R.id.showResult);

        calculateResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int result = 0;

                if (red.isChecked()) {
                    result += 10;
                }

                if (blue.isChecked()) {
                    result += 20;
                }

                if (white.isChecked()) {
                    result += 30;
                }

                showResult.setText(result);

            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for the corrections, null_override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox red;
    CheckBox blue;
    CheckBox white;
    Button calculateResult;

    Integer[] checkBoxValues = {10, 20, 30};
    int result = 0;
    int redValue = 0, blueValue = 0, whiteValue = 0;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        red = findViewById(R.id.red);
        blue = findViewById(R.id.blue);
        white = findViewById(R.id.white);
        calculateResult = findViewById(R.id.calculateResult);
        final TextView showResult = findViewById(R.id.showResult);


        calculateResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (red.isChecked()) redValue = checkBoxValues[0];
                else redValue = 0;

                if (blue.isChecked()) blueValue = checkBoxValues[1];
                else blueValue = 0;

                if (white.isChecked()) whiteValue = checkBoxValues[2];
                else whiteValue = 0;

                result = redValue + blueValue + whiteValue;
                showResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI.